# Retrieving data instead of data id from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Hi i am working on php and mysql.

I have a form where in i am accessing data from one table and upon selection i am inserting that data in to another table. But my major constraint is the selected data id is being stored instead of the data value.

kindly let me know how to get the data value instead of the data id.

Below is the sample code.

```
<td>Status:</td>
                    <td>   <select name="status" id="status">
          <?php $svar = mysql_query("select * from status");
          while($sresult = mysql_fetch_array($svar)){ ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $sresult['id']; ?>" <?php if($sresult['id']==$row['status']){ echo "selected"; }?> /><?php  echo $sresult['status']; ?></option>
          <?php } ?>
                        </select> </td>
```

Now i am inserting the data from the above form in to another database using the following query:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Createticket (......,status) VALUES(..........,'$status')";
```

Comment: [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1190388) in new code. They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the red box? Learn about prepared statements instead, and use [tag:PDO] or [tag:MySQLi].

Comment: the value of `status` is `result[id]` as set by your html, if you need the value you need to change the `value=` of the `<option`

Comment: since the value attribute is sent through the POST, it's normal to recieve the id, when you have `value=<?=$sresult['id']`, change it to the column you want to send

Comment: MORE CODE!!  This should produce a working dropdown.  Have you tried var_dump($_POST) to see what it is sending?  This will tell you if your problem is with this code, or the next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you left out quite a chunk of your code which would have helped check 100%, I think I can make an educated guess at what your attempting.

It's simply because you are setting the value of the select box as the id, not the value....

Change this line:

```
<option value="<?php echo $sresult['id']; ?>" <?php if($sresult['id']==$row['status']){ echo "selected"; }?> /><?php  echo $sresult['status']; ?></option>
```

to:

```
<option value="<?php echo $sresult['status']; ?>" <?php if($sresult['id']==$row['status']){ echo "selected"; }?> /><?php  echo $sresult['status']; ?></option>
```

That way, when you post the form, you are posting the value of the field 'status', as the status value not the id value of $result.

Comment: I thought the same. I want to add: `<option value="[this is what gets send over to the next script]">[this is only a label, not a value that gets sent]</option>`

Comment: J5Dev that helped me out thanks for the reply. Hope to get back to you if i get any other queries.

Answer (score 0):

the value you are assigning to the option field is $sresult['id'] so the same id is stored in the second table to set the status

replace the

```
    value = " <?php echo $sresult['id'] ?> "
```

with in oprtions filed to

```
    value = " <?php echo $sresult['status'] ?> "
```